# How can I get the image url in WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using this code to get all images uploaded to a page and it's working fine but I'd like to use the image urls for a lightbox function and currently I'm getting an `img` object. Is there any way I can get the image url specifically? I'd like to think it's part of an array. Here's the code I'm using:

```
<?php
    $images = get_children( array(
    'post_parent' => $post->ID, 
    'post_type' => 'attachment', 
    'post_mime_type' => 'image', 
    'orderby' => 'menu_order', 
    'order' => 'ASC', 
    'numberposts' => 999 ) ); 
    if ( $images ) { 
        //looping through the images
        foreach ( $images as $attachment_id => $attachment ) {
        ?>
<li>
<a href="*the_img_url*" data-lightbox="lightbox-1" data-title="<?php echo $attachment->post_excerpt; ?>" ><?php echo wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment_id, 'full' ); ?>
</a>
</li>
<?php
}
}
?>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried

```
<?php echo wp_get_attachment_url( $attachment_id ); ?>  
// $attachment_id is  The ID of the desired attachment
```

Comment: Thank you, this works perfectly! I'll accept your answer as soon as it lets me. Enjoy your day